# How to convert complex Xml to csv?

Tags: java, xml, xslt

I am writing a program in java( pre-junior), I really need help with xslt transformation. It is necessary to make a csv file from xml.
I got this xslt filter:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="no"/>

    <xsl:template match="node()" name="conv">
        <xsl:call-template name="loop"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="loop">

        <xsl:for-each select="./*[count(*) = 0]">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            <xsl:if test="position() != last()">
                <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:if test="position() = last()">
                <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>


        <xsl:for-each select="./*[(count(*) != 0) and (name()!='PARAMETRS')] ">
            <xsl:call-template name="loop"/>
        </xsl:for-each>
            <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Source xml:

```
<Integration>
    <PARAMETRS>
        <ID>AZD</ID>
        <DATE>2020-01-01</DATE>
    </PARAMETRS>
    <ORG>
        <Thing>
            <object>10220</object>
            <type>U</type>
            <dyn>
                <items>
                    <val>988009</val>
                    <datebegin>2019-12-12</datebegin>
                </items>
            </dyn>
        </Thing>
        <Thing>
            <object>10221</object>
            <type>U</type>
            <dyn>
                <items>
                    <val>988010</val>
                    <datebegin>2019-12-13</datebegin>
                </items>
                <items>
                    <val>988011</val>
                    <datebegin>2019-12-14</datebegin>
                </items>
            </dyn>
        </Thing>
    </ORG>
</Integration>
```

In the output, I get comma-separated lines, and a few more lines (those same items) with the values below. and can't figure out how to concatenate the values ...
I would do it via value-of select = "concat" but my  may have several dyn (1, 2, 3 ...), hence this is not suitable.
The output needs a csv separated by commas.
Please advise how to concatenate the item with its parent? Or there are simpler ways to parse xml with a different number of subsections(childs).

Expected output:

```
10220,U,988009,2019-12-12
10221,U,988010,2019-12-13,988011,2019-12-14
```

Comment: Please show the expected output in your example. -- Hint: generic stylesheets very often do not work as expected when the input is not what the author envisaged.

Comment: Expected output:
10220,U,988009,2019-12-12 and next Thing below
10221,U,988010,2019-12-13,988011,2019-12-14

Comment: Please don't post code in comments - edit your question instead. Make sure we can see clearly which elements in the input should create a new row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The output you show can be easily obtained using the following stylesheet:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text"/>

<xsl:template match="/Integration">
    <xsl:for-each select="ORG/Thing">
        <xsl:value-of select="object"/>
        <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="type"/>
        <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
        <xsl:for-each select="dyn/items">
            <xsl:value-of select="val"/>
            <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="datebegin"/>
            <xsl:if test="position() != last()">
                <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

Note that the output has a set of columns for each `items`; this is not an ideal CSV structure.

Comment: Great! You safe my time!

Answer (score 0):

If you can use XSLT 2.0, it opens up new powerful functionality.

Oracle XML Developer Kit (XDK) supports XSLT 2.0

Here is the link: [Using the XSLT Processor for Java](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/adxdk/using-XSLT-processor-for-Java.html#GUID-E148A072-BDBE-40A4-A393-F4FC362382F5)

The approach below is doing the following:

- Using `string-join()` function to concatenate all child elements values
  on a different hierarchy level via `.//*/(text()[1]` expression.
- `xs:token` casting removes white spaces.
- XPath predicate `[. != '']` removes empty sequence members.

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xsl:output method="text"/>

    <xsl:template match="/Integration">
        <xsl:for-each select="ORG/Thing">
            <xsl:value-of select="string-join((.//*/(text()[1] cast as xs:token?))[. != ''],',')"/>
            <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

> Output

```
10220,U,988009,2019-12-12
10221,U,988010,2019-12-13,988011,2019-12-14
```

Based on the Marting Honnen great tip, here is even more concise XSLT 2.0 version without any loop.

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xsl:output method="text"/>

    <xsl:template match="/Integration">
        <xsl:value-of select="ORG/Thing/string-join((.//*/(text()[1] cast as xs:token?))[. != ''],',')" separator="&#xA;"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: In XSLT 2 it is even possible to write more compact code to create the lines in the CSV using `xsl:value-of separator` instead of your nested `xsl:for-each`/`xsl:value-of`: `<xsl:value-of select="ORG/Thing/string-join((.//*/(text()[1] cast as xs:token?))[. != ''],',')" separator="&#xA;"/>`.